# How to pass the class of activity to the intent which this activity has opened?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-preferences

I am working on a project where I have come over a problem. My main activity is a list of sites I need to parse. I am making a preferences window. Inside of it I can choose which sites I want to see in the main activity and which I don't (checkboxes). I also have a couple more preferences (show the images or not) for other activities. The preference activity is accessible from any other activity through the NavigationDrawer. I haven't found a good answer on how to refresh the main page correctly so I have come to a conclusion that I need to restart the activity when I press the back button. The problem is I want to restart the activity that has opened the Preference Activity. Is there a way to pass the class through the intent so that I know what activity I want to open?

Comment: It sounds like the path you are thinking of going down is going to mess up your back stack. Have you tried refreshing the data in each Activity in `onResume()` instead?

Comment: @DanielNugent I actually have thought about it but it seems that `onResume()` works not only when I go back to the activity but in some more cases too. By the way I have read somewhere here that it is not a very good way to do that. And the last thing. I have tried it but I might have understood the idea wrong so it didn't work like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

create a static activity in preference activity, and assign current activity to it before starting preference activity. and after finishing preference activity refresh current activity

preference Activity

```
 public class PreferenceAtivity extends Activity {
      public static Activity currentActivity;

      pubic void save(View v) {
         finish();
         currentActivity.recreate();
     }
}
```

another activity

```
 public class AnotherAtivity extends Activity {


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.preference) {
            PreferenceActivity.currentActivity = this;
            startAtivity(new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
```

Comment: ok, I have a question about this. If I undestood what you mean you want me to create an object of a class that calls the `PreferenceActivity` inside the `PreferenceActivity` and then assign my activity to that created object? If I misunderstood correct me please. How do I actually assign it to the object if I never create a `PreferenceActivity` because I simply call it out with Intent?

Comment: create a static activity object. so that any activity can be assigned to it.

Comment: but I don't have a PreferenceActivity object. Or do you mean to make the class static?

Comment: Did you test it? Because it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: this is something i do all the time